# Function-specified Filter clause doesn't work for getting Sharepoint item list in Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get a list of SharePoint items using Graph API with a Filter clause, but I get an error when I specify a function such as StartsWith.

The following page says, "Support for the $filter operator varies depending on the Microsoft Graph API. Commonly supported are the following logical operators." Is it possible to use them?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter

■In the case of eq, data can be retrieved
/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?$expand=fields&$filter=fields/Title eq 'test'

■In the case of startsWith, an error will occur saying it is an invalid filter clause.

/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?$expand=fields&$filter=fields/Title startsWith 'test'

ErrorMessage :

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Invalid filter clause",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-07-13T02:09:30",
            "request-id": "5f84935b-59f1-46cf-a160-18d64e989eb7",
            "client-request-id": "e417c442-123d-ba3b-1465-8ff7f4f78645"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this way, https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/lists/[id]/items?expand=fields&amp;$filter=fields/Title startswith &#'test'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify `startswith` in your Graph API URL as :

```
$filter=startswith(fields/Title,'test')
```